# How to call router file function from component .ts file in angular js 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am a beginner in angular and I have build a simple angular project where I am trying to call a method from browser. But the method mentioned in router file is not called from component type script file and showing the error i.e.
**GET http://localhost:3000/User/register net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** in google chrome and in firefox browser it is showing **Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/User/register. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).**. Please help me to resolve this problem. Below I have attached my code please check.

```
**login.component.html FILE**
<p>login works!</p>

<form #userEntryForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="getEntry(userEntryForm.value)">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Get Value</button>
            </td> 
        </tr>
        <div>{{showMsg}}</div>
    </table>

</form>
---------------------------------------------------------------
**login.component.ts FILE**
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getEntry(formData):void{
    this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/User/register").subscribe(
      res=>{
        console.log(res);
      }
    );
  }
}
-------------------------------------------------------------
**Server.js file**
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express()
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false})
);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
  });

var Users = require("./src/routes/Users"); //./src/app/routes/Users

app.use("/users", Users);

app.listen(port,function(){
    console.log("Server is running on port "+port);
```

### })

```
**Router file(User.js)**
const express = require('express')
const users = express.Router()
const cors = require("cors")
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
//const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
var app = express()
//const User = require
users.use(cors())

var dboper = require('../app/dbconfig/dboperation');


app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
  });


users.get('/register', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log("rows");
  dboper.register(function (err, rows) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(rows,"errer");
          res.json(err);
      }
      else {
          console.log(rows,"ef3refr3r");
          res.json(rows);
      }
  });
});

module.exports = users

----------------------------------------------------------
**package.json file**
{
  "name": "firstapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server.js",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.22",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.22",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't call `this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/User/register")`, but simply `this.http.get("/User/register")`. The rest is figured out automatically. No need for CORS when you call your own server. Also, this is not AngularJS but Angular.

Comment: when I am Calling it with this.http.get("/User/register") the it show the msg i.e. http://localhost:4200/User/register 404 (Not Found). in the file zone-evergreen.js:2952

Comment: Well, that's because you're serving your Angular app with the default, integrated server (`ng serve)`, which runs on port 4200. Of course, the built-in server is a convenient development tool but does not have a `/User/register` route. You have to stop using the built-in server and start using your own, which apparently runs on port 3000. Compile your app to files with `ng build`, then use your own server to serve these files. Access the app on localhost:3000 and call your server on `get("/User/register")`.